# NOW() function isn't saving the current server's timezone, it is using the UNIX timestamp adding 8 extra hours

Tags: php, mysql

Suddenly, the `NOW()` function stopped saving the server's time and now I have a mess printing data using the 'time ago' implementation. It is weird.

My server's time (Hosting & MySQL) is -07:00 GMT (7:45am).
My current time is: -04:00 GMT Eastern Daylight Time (10:45am).

I already corroborated the server's time using local functions.

If I save something using `NOW()`, the time in the field is (`2015-09-04 15:45:40`)... it is adding 8 hours ahead, I don't know why, It was working fine.

So, now I'm wondering what would be the best way to fix this?  Thanks for any advice.

**UPDATE**

I just found out that server is using the UNIX timestamp to save things on Database.

```
So, my current time: -04:00 (13:48)
Server current timezone -07:00 (10:48)
Server UNIX timestamp: GMT (17:48)
```

Not sure if this information works to find a solution. I want it saves things using the *server current timezone*.

**UPDATE 2**

Only solution found so far was using the `date` function instead of `NOW()` which uses the hosting server time, not the database's.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

This implies making changes in all scripts where I was using `NOW()`...geez!

Comment: Maybe you set your session time zone, so it's displaying in a different timezone than normal.

Comment: using mysql client, issue command and verify it is set to SYSTEM: 

show variables where Variable_name = 'time_zone';

Comment: @Barmar How I can check if I set my session time zone to a different one?

Comment: `SELECT @@session.time_zone;` like in the answer.

Comment: @Barmar, I tried it that one, but I got: "#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation". I don't have direct access to my MySQL server.

Comment: You got that error for a `SELECT` query? I thought you got that when you tried to do `SET @@global.time_zone`.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19069310/3976261) :

1. check `my.cnf` for `default_time_zone='+00:00'` section.
2. execute this query `SELECT @@global.time_zone;` and, if needed, change the values

`SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+8:00';
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki';
SET @@global.time_zone='+00:00';`

3. execute this query `SELECT @@session.time_zone;` and, if needed, change the values

`SET time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki';
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
SET @@session.time_zone = "+00:00";`

Comment: I don't have direct access to the server, only through phpMyAdmin. I executed SELECT @@session.time_zone; SET time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles'; SET time_zone = "-07:00"; SET @@session.time_zone = "-07:00"; which is the time zone of the server, but it didn't solve the problem. Not sure how to check my.cnf.

Comment: I got "#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation " trying to use SET GLOBAL time_zone

Comment: if you are on a shared hosting, can you ask the hosting provider's administrators to give you the needed permissions (or to execute the queries for you)?

Comment: I don't think the inoperative people of G.D. let me do that, but I'll try. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well... if you don't have the permissions to change something, and obviously it was changed, there is a pretty good chance that they messed up somehow...

Answer (score 2):

Try adding [date_default_timezone_set](http://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set) to the top of your script, and then use [date](http://www.php.net/date) instead of `NOW()`

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: That sure is a working option, but it is better to be used when you have a specific script that needs the different timezone. It could cause a pain in the ass if you forget to add it on a page every time. I don't think that's the author's goal.

Comment: I added **date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');** at the top of my script which is the time zone of the server, but it is still adding 8 extra hours when saving into the DB

Comment: mariobgr is right, if this is a solution, I'd have to change algorithms in over 50 different files and scripts... it would be a p.i.t.a... it was working fine, saving things with the server's time, not sure what happened.